# strange initial-scaling behaviour for viewport

Tags: viewport, samsung-mobile

I am trying to understand how viewport and initial-scaling works. I read [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Mobile/Viewport_meta_tag), [this](http://www.javascriptkit.com/dhtmltutors/cssmediaqueries3.shtml) and [this](http://www.quirksmode.org/mobile/viewports2.html) and tried the following experiment, which I can reproduce on a samsung galaxy s4 using firefox version 43.0.

If I open a webpage on the galaxy s4 containing this code:

```
  <!DOCTYPE html >
<html >
  <head>
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
    <title>Test</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=300px, initial-scale=2.0"/>    
  </head>
  <body>
    <div style='background-color:red;width:100%'>Adam 8</div>           
  </body>
</html>
```

then I get the following result:

[image]

This makes sense to me, because the div has a width of 300 CSS pixel, the galaxy s4 has 640 device pixel, and initial-scale=2 should force my phone to use 600 device pixel to represent the 300 CSS pixel div-container, which gives a blank space of 40 device pixel (however, the blank space does look wider then 40 device pixel to me but I will ignore it for now).
Then, I changed the *initial-scale* from 2 to 1:

```
<!DOCTYPE html >
<html >
  <head>
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
    <title>Test</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=300px, initial-scale=1.0"/>


  </head>
  <body>
    <div style='background-color:red;width:100%'>Adam 9</div>

  </body>
</html>
```

Since initial-scale=1, I assumed that my phone only uses 300 device pixel to represent the red bar. However, I get this:

[image]

Why is the redbar now 640 device pixel long instead of 300 device pixel?

Answer (score 0):

In your second example, your viewport meta tag is over-constrained. The browser will limit the minimum zoom level such that you can't zoom out to see beyond the extents of the content. In your case, the content is ~300px and the screen size is 640px so the minimum-zoom level would be ~2.1. However, you specified initial-scale=1.0 so there's no way to realize that. In this case, the browser chose to honor the initial-scale by extending the content-width to allow the specified scale.

The first case is a little more puzzling to me as the same thing should be happening to a lesser extent. Here's a [picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mrass.png) of how it looks in Chrome on my Nexus 4 which has the same screen height.

In general, the viewport meta tag isn't specified and the behavior in these kinds of cases will vary by browser. I would avoid setting the initial-scale at all and let the browser do that automatically. Typically they will try to zoom out to fit all the content on the screen.